# partial views to get data and then post the results to save in database

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-partialview

I am very new to MVC, let me try to explain my scenario in plain simple English:

I have  an strongly typed mvc form/page (`Product.cshtml`) with a model, say `ProductViewModel`.

This page has got two search buttons, one to search and bring the items to be added to the Product and other to bring in the location, most probably partial views.

Now, what I want is that these search results work in ajax form without complete post back, and then the results of these searches (items and location) should be posted back using model binding to the form when user clicks on the submit button.

What could be the best way of achieving this functionality?

Immediate responses will be well appreciated.

---

I thought, its good to share the complete code for clarity:

I have one form(Service1.chtml) that has a partial view to display users(_TestUser a partial view:read only), then another partial view(_PlotServiceRequestData) that should have a field to search the plot and bring back the details lke its owner name and landuser etc.

Then when I click on submit button of the main form, I should be able to read all data(main form) + new data from _PlotServiceRequestData partial view and save all data to database.

I was trying one more option, that is, to use @Ajax.ActionLink on Service1.cshtml to call the _GetPlotDetails method and then store partial view data in TempData, so that it is available to the form when users clicks on "Submit" button of Service1.cshtml, is this a right approach?, if I use ajax.BeginForm inside partial view then the data is posted to the

Service1 controller method which is actually to save the form data and not to update the partialview and in this method even I am not getting model data of the partial view.

```
Sevice1.cshtml:

@model ViewModels.TestViewModel

@{

    ViewBag.Title =




"Service1";

}

@




using (Html.BeginForm())

{

@Html.LabelFor(m => m.Title)

@Html.EditorFor(m => m.Title)

    @Html.Partial(




"_TestUser", Model)






<div id="RequestPlotData">

        @Html.Partial(




"_PlotServiceRequestData", Model.requestData)






</div>






<button type="submit">Save Form</button>

}

@section Scripts {

}



_PlotServiceRequestData.cshtml:

===============================



@model ViewModels.PlotServicesRequestDataViewModel



<













div id="RequestPlotData">



    @








using (Ajax.BeginForm("_GetPlotDetails", "Test", new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId = "RequestPlotData", Url = Url.Action("_GetPlotDetails","Test") }))



    {












<h1>Request Details</h1>



　












<div>



        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.plotAddress)



        @Html.EditorFor(m => m.plotAddress)












<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Ajax Post" />












</div>
















<div>



        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.LandUser)



        @Html.EditorFor(m => m.LandUser)












</div>












<div>



        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.OwnerName)



        @Html.EditorFor(m => m.OwnerName)












</div>



    }



</













div>





CONTROLLER:

==========





using













 System;



using













 System.Collections.Generic;



using













 System.Linq;



using













 System.Web;



using













 System.Web.Mvc;




namespace













 TestNameSpace



{












public class TestController : Controller



    {












//












// GET: /Test/












public ActionResult Service1()



        {



            Injazat.AM.mServices.








LocalDBEntities context = new Injazat.AM.mServices.LocalDBEntities();



TestViewModel model =








new TestViewModel() { user = context.Users.First(), Title = "Land Setting Out", 



                requestData =








new PlotServicesRequestDataViewModel() { ServiceNumber ="122345", TransactionDate="10/10/2033" } };
















return View(model);



        }



        [








HttpPost()]












public ActionResult Service1(TestViewModel model)



        {



            PlotServicesRequestDataViewModel s = (PlotServicesRequestDataViewModel)TempData[








"Data"];



            TestViewModel vm =








new TestViewModel() { user = model.user, requestData = s, Title = model.Title };












return View(vm);



　



        }



        [








HttpGet()]












//public PartialViewResult _GetPlotDetails(string add)












public PartialViewResult _GetPlotDetails(PlotServicesRequestDataViewModel requestData)



        {
















//PlotServicesRequestDataViewModel requestData = new PlotServicesRequestDataViewModel() {  plotAddress = add};



            requestData.OwnerName =








"owner";



            requestData.LandUser =








"landuser";



            TempData[








"Data"] = requestData;












return PartialView("_PlotServiceRequestData", requestData);



        }



    }



}
```

Comment: Please post the code for what you have done so far.

Answer (score 0):

You can probably use the [jQuery Form plugin](http://malsup.com/jquery/form/) for this.  This makes the process of posting the data from your form back to the server very easy.  The form would post to an action that would return a partial view that you can then push into your UI.

To make this easier, jQuery form actually has a "target" option where it will automatically update with the server response (ie. the partial view returned from your search action).

**View**

```
<form id="searchForm" action="@(Url.Action("Search"))" method="POST">
    <input name="query" type="text" /> <!-- order use Html.TextBoxFor() here -->
    <input type="submit" />
</form>
<div id="result"><!--result here--></div>
```

**Javascript**

```
$('#searchForm').ajaxForm({
 target: '#result'
});
```

**Controller**

```
public ActionResult Search(string query)
{
    // Do something with query
    var model = GetSearchResults(query);

    return Partial("SearchResults", model)
}
```

This should hopefully help you to get on the right track.  jQuery Form is a good plugin and is the main thing you should look into for ajaxifying your form posts back to the server.  You might also want to look into using jQuery's `$.post` and `$.ajax` functions, but these require slightly more work.